# Javascript/jQuery: remove shape/path from canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I can't seem to find the function to remove a shape or path from the canvas after it has been created.

So I'm creating a bezier curve between 2 points with

```
beginPath();
bezierCurveTo();
stroke();
closePath();
```

How can I remove this from the canvas once it's been created? I need to be able to call the remove function via `toggle()` and `blur()`. I'm sure something exists for this...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I just wanted to mention that the use of `closePath()` here and in many of the answers is wrong. It is used to complete a path by drawing a line to the path's start. Calling it after `stroke` does **absolutely nothing.** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807230/what-exactly-is-a-canvas-path-and-what-is-the-use-of-ctx-closepath

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the great input to all of you - it helped me find the solution:

```
context.clearRect(x,y,w,h);
```

([link](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-clearrect))

This will clear anything within that rectangle.

I found the method on the page I found while digging for ILog's answer to save/restore the context, and it's all on there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
// drawing here you path second time
ctx.restore();
```

> "The globalCompositeOperation attribute sets how shapes and images are drawn onto the scratch bitmap" [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#compositing)

How it works you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html).

Answer (score 13):

This is an important thing to realise about `<canvas>`. It's a flattened image made up of pixels. Once something's drawn to it, it's merged into the pixel grid and cannot be differentiated from the other pixels.

If you need to be able to separate image elements you could:

1. Overlay `<canvas>` elements into a stack of layers
2. Use `<svg>` in which each visual element is distinct from the other elements and may be manipulated independently

You can think of `<canvas>` as being a single layer in PhotoShop/Gimp/Fireworks, or an MSPaint document.

You can think of `<svg>` as a document in Illustrator/InkScape.

Answer (score 5):

You can't remove a path/shape from the canvas. You can draw something else over it or clear the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using SVG instead of canvas.  There's a fantastic library called [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) that makes working with SVG a breeze.  It works in all browsers too, including IE6.

With SVG each shape is its own element that can be moved, transformed, or removed.

Comment: A retrospective comment here - if you are drawing a lot, SVG will generally be less performant than canvas. I am currently refactoring an app that does a lot of drawing in SVG to using canvas.

Answer (score 1):

To clear your canvas, use the following code

```
    canvas_context.clearRect(0,0,canvas_1.width,canvas_1.height);
```

Always use **beginPath** method when you are starting to draw a new path and **closePath** method after you finished drawing your path.

> **NOTE:** *Paths that are not closed cannot be cleared.*

If your paths are not getting cleared, it must be because of the above reason.

<strike>All path MUST begin with **beginPath()** and end with **closePath()**</strike>

Example:

```
     canvas_context.beginPath();
     canvas_context.moveTo(x1,y1);
     canvas_context.lineTo(x2,y2);
     canvas_context.stroke();
     canvas_context.closePath();
```

The following code also clears your canvas

```
    canvas_1.width = canvas_1.width;
```

> **NOTE:** *The above statement reinitializes a canvas hence it clears a canvas. Any statement that reinitializes a canvas will clear a canvas.*

Comment: "All path MUST begin with beginPath() and end with closePath()" - Wrong! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807230/what-exactly-is-a-canvas-path-and-what-is-the-use-of-ctx-closepath

Comment: Just tested that again in my Chrome and you are right. Back in 2011 when I tested this in Chrome, the paths that were not closed never got cleared. Anyway, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the specification you must call context.save() before drawing, then draw something, and then call context.restore() to return to the previous state.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried this (unsuccessfully) and then found this resource (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-state) stating:

"The current path and the current bitmap are not part of the drawing state. The current path is persistent, and can only be reset using the beginPath()  method. The current bitmap is a property of the canvas, not the context."

Thanks anyway though, much appreciated!

Comment: save/restore only operate upon certain properties of the context, and calling them will never have a visible effect on the image if you don't draw something afterwards. [This article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_states.htm) provides more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery:

```
var elem = $("selector");
var canvas = elem.get(0);
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.beginPath();
```

Replace "selector" with your actual JQuery selector.