# What exactly is a canvas path, and what is the use of ctx.closePath()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing, jcanvas

I'm working on an HTML5 game. I need to draw tail lines in the canvas and check for intersections in the game, which is a Tron-style game.

I'm actually using [the `drawLine()` function from JCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs.php?p=lines), but JCanvas did not provide me a way to check for line intersection, I digged in the source and found the use the `ctx` object, and at the end of the function I'm using, I returned the object so I can use the `ctx.isPointInPath()` method to achieve what I need, but is not working, is returning `false` everytime...

I really don't understand what a path is - will `ctx.isPointInPath()` return `true` just for the points that are set using `ctx.moveTo()` after `ctx.beginPath()`? Or will it return `true` for all the points that are between 2 consecutive `ctx.moveTo()`s that are connected using `ctx.lineTo()`?

What is the use of `ctx.closePath()`?

And what is the difference between:

```
{
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

and:

```
{
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Comment: Reference: the [specification on `closePath()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-closepath).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### What is a path?

It's a series of path commands (moveTo, lineTo, arcTo, etc.) that define the boundary of a vector shape. You can then fill and/or stroke the path as desired.

### What is the Use of `closePath()`?

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YrQCG/5/

```
// Draw a red path using closePath() in the middle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.moveTo(50,100);
ctx.lineTo(100,150);
ctx.lineTo(150,100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.lineTo(50,50);
ctx.stroke();

// Slide the next path over by 150 pixels    
ctx.translate(150,0);

// Draw a blue path using the exact same commands, but without closePath
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.moveTo(50,100);
ctx.lineTo(100,150);
ctx.lineTo(150,100);
//ctx.closePath();
ctx.lineTo(50,50);
ctx.stroke();
```

[image]

Using `closePath()` causes the point of the pen to move back to the start of the current subpath, **drawing a line from the current point back to that starting point**; the next command starts from this new point. It's useful if you want to draw a fully outlined shape without explicitly drawing the last line.

It is equivalent to calling `lineTo()` with the location of the first point of your current subpath, followed by `moveTo()` to that same point (to establish a new subpath).

- Seen above, we draw a `V` symbol using the first `moveTo` and following two `lineTo` commands. When we call `closePath` on the red path it draws the horizontal bar across and causes the next line to start from the top left corner.
- When we don't call `closePath` in the blue path the next `lineTo` command continues on from the last drawn point.

Note that `closePath()` is *not* necessary most of the time, unlike `beginPath()` which you must call each time you want to start drawing a new path. (If you don't, all the old path drawing commands are part of the next drawing.)

Comment: Thanks (: ... just one final question .isPointInPath() will evaluate against the last path (even if its alredy closed) ??

Comment: There is only ever one path (which may have subpaths). The method [`isPointInPath()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-ispointinpath) will test against the entire path (all subpaths), including whether or not `closePath()` drew a line or not. (Note that the statement _"there is only ever one path"_ applies to the context; you can, alternatively, create [`Path`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#path-objects) objects.

Comment: @Aronis See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kLZfc/3/): `isPointInPath()` does not account for stroke, but tests the equivalent filled area of the path (the yellow in that demo). The point `50,50` is directly along the edge of one of the lines, but adjacent to no filled regions.

Comment: And here's another demo showing a case where the test succeeds for a point exactly on the edge of the path, but adjacent to a non-zero fill region: http://jsfiddle.net/kLZfc/4/

Answer (score 18):

This is the basic representation of closed path:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(100,0);
ctx.lineTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(0,100);    
ctx.closePath(); // <--the image right side has this line
ctx.stroke();
```

The result of `closePath()` is that the start and the end point will be bounded.

[image: closed path]