# Why,after creating several objects on javascript canvas animation, they are connected?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have problem with javascript canvas.
I'm trying to put on canvas several object which are moving and bouncing on edges of canvas. If i create one object, there is no problem with it, but if i want to create more objects, they become connected.

```
Fiddle example:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwbgwa39/

I will be very thankfull if someone could help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important thing is to call `beginPath()` at the begining of each object drawing and `closePath()` when you are done drawing that object. If you don't call it canvas thinks that you are trying to continue drawing last object. You can read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/closePath)

```
        for(i in obj_t)
            {
                ctx.beginPath();
                obj_t[i].xPos = obj_t[i].xPos + obj_t[i].xVel;
                obj_t[i].yPos = obj_t[i].yPos + obj_t[i].yVel;
                ctx.arc(obj_t[i].xPos, obj_t[i].yPos, obj_t[i].r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);


                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath(); // optional
            }
```

EDIT: As Kaiido noticed calling `closePath()` in this example is not necessary. More info on when you should call `closePath()` [can be found in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807230/what-exactly-is-a-canvas-path-and-what-is-the-use-of-ctx-closepath).

Comment: Thank you! :) Works perfectly :)

Comment: closePath is just a lineTo(firstPoint). Useless for a circle shape, it won't "end" the path declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You're drawing a path. Each time you draw something it continues the path you have made so far. You can move beginPath into the for loop to start a new path for each circle:

```
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        for(i in obj_t)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            // draw here
        }
        ctx.closePath();
```

See in action: https://jsfiddle.net/mwbgwa39/4/

Comment: Thank you! :) Works perfectly :)

Comment: closePath is just a lineTo(firstPoint). Useless for a circle shape, it won't "end" the path declaration.

Comment: @Kaiido, correct, I didn't even have it when I tested. The beginPath at the beginning of the look is what does the effect. I just included the closePath, but maybe I'll move it after the look